# Strange issue when creating a new file

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have the below 2 methods, supposed to read and write to a file:

```
/* Write content to a file */
    private void writeToFile(ArrayList<String> list) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        File file = new File("jokesBody1.bjk");
        FileOutputStream fos;
        if(list != null){
        try {           
                fos = openFileOutput("jokesBody1.bjk",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                out.writeObject(list);
                out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        }else{
            try {
                fos = openFileOutput("jokesBody1.bjk",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                out.writeObject("");
                out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        }
    }

    /* Read file's content */
    private ArrayList<String> readFromFile() {
        File file = new File("jokesBody1.bjk");
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream( new FileInputStream( file ) );
            try {
                list = (ArrayList)ois.readObject();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ois.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("log activity", "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
        }

        return list;
    }
```

When I'm calling the above methods I'm getting this error:

```
02-15 10:28:48.165: E/log activity(1743): Can not read file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /jokesBody1.bjk: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Ok, it clearly says that the file is not there, but, isn't this code supposed to create it:

```
File file = new File("jokesBody1.bjk");
```

Why I'm getting this error? I know that I'm missing something small - probably a piece of code that creates the file(I'm not sure), but as a beginner, I'm not able to spot the issue.

Comment: `File file = new File("jokesBody1.bjk");` I don't think that necessarily makes a new file on the filesystem, but rather just makes a file object inside your app. I think you want the method `create NewFile()`. You can read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
File file = new File("jokesBody1.bjk");
```

Just creates a File objects that points to that path, but no actual file.

Use

```
file.createNewFile();
```

To actually create the file.

Answer (score 1):

> Ok, it clearly says that the file is not there, but, isn't this code supposed to create it:

Actually, no. It only creates a File object, an then java assumes that file to exist.